# Проверка правописания в Atom ( код на JavaScript )

Tags: javascript, atom

Как правильно настроить плагин `"Spell Check"` в Atom, чтобы он корректно проверял правописание?
Я добавил флаги в настройки грамматики :

> source.asciidoc, source.gfm, text.git-commit, text.plain, text.plain.null-grammar, source.js, meta.method-call.js, meta.arguments.js, string.quoted.double.js.

После `source.js` оно подчеркивает переменные слепленные из 2 слов, слепленные через подчеркивания или через точку.

Добавил языковые локации : `en-US`, `ru-RU`.

Как настроить его нормально под JavaScript?

Comment: можно пример того что есть и того что вы хотите видеть?

Comment: Видел что в VS Code проверка орфографии работает нормально, но сам не использовал её.

Answer (score 0):

"spell-check" не работает с самого начала. Есть два способа: первый отключить, второй это поставить исправляющие плагины, но не факт, что это сработает.
**spell-check-urls**, **spell-check-project**, **spell-check-test**